# I don't have a company, how to fill in organization name in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I just want to build up apps by myself in Xcode, I am now a student, I don't own a company, but when I when to create a new project, I have to fill in the bar called "Organization name", since I don't run a company now and I don't want to set a company name randomly because I don't want to cause any troubles related to it.
How to fill in the name of a company here in Xcode??

Comment: fill it with Apple. or Microsoft. or Damage Inc. It doesn't matter

Comment: Is this behavior some kind of infringement to those existing corporations? And will the name of the organization be shown somewhere after I publish the app?

Comment: no, it does not shown anywhere and you're not going to be taken to court for using these names

Answer (score 2):

This is just for some documentation purpose for the Product or APP Bunldle ID of the application when later on you get to publish the application, you get to give the same Bundle id that is of your application, which in term is autofilled by reverse DNS process. Eg - `com.yourOrganizationName.applicationName`. This is the bundle id of your app which makes your app unique. Right now you can give it whatever you want. So your application would have a ID of 
`com.WhatEverYouWant.yourApplicationName`. This is of significance only when you have a developer account and you want to publish your application.

Comment: Yes I do have a Apple developer account and I do want to publish it, so, how to deal with it now ? Thank you for your notice

Comment: just give anything you want, any pet name or anything meaningfull to you, as i said how the bundle id will be constructed, so the final bundle id must be Unique to the whole of app store.